# MySQL error: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!

Tags: mysql

I get this error when trying to start MySQL: `The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!`

Here is the output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1       455G   77G  356G  18% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            1,9G  4,0K  1,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           387M  1,3M  386M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            1,9G  1,2M  1,9G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   28K  100M   1% /run/user
```

This shows that the partition is nowhere near full.

Comment: what is the size of the binairy log in /var/lib/mysql/?

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but which one is the correct log: ib_logfile0 or ib_logfile1?

Comment: hmm I would think "server-bin.*" or "mysql-bin.*".

Comment: There seem to be no such files in /var/lib/mysql. I've even reinstalled mysql-server, but nothing changed.

Comment: whcih version are u you using please describe that

Comment: What about your inodes? `dh -i`

Comment: i got same problem on virtual machine, but here i forgot to expand the disk from 8gb to 2tb so this post resorve my problem, thanks :)

Answer (score 13):

I finally fixed it by running `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`. I just had to insert `sudo` in front of the command.

Comment: How can this fix the issue? The OP got this error when trying to start MySQL, and this command do nothing to help.

Comment: @PaulLo it really helps. I forgot to add `sudo`.

Comment: I don't understand how this got 8 upvotes.

Comment: This fixed it for me. I don't know why this works but it does. I was getting the error saying the partition is full when trying to start mysql. I ran the command using sudo and mysql started just fine.

Comment: Wow, `sudo service mysql restart` was saying everything was good, but running this command actually fixed the problem. I don't get the difference ...

Answer (score 6):

try this:

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo service mysql start
```

Comment: i had the same problem 'The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!' and i fixed it this way!

Comment: @KasiyA yes it is an answer to the question (but it is the same as the answer given by rocketgear himself) (stop/start will fix this notice)

Comment: @Rinzwind uhh. sorry

Comment: in my case `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` doesn't work....

Answer (score 3):

In my case the error resulted of changing the ip address on the server.

```
cat /var/log/mysql/error.log

150427 23:01:08 InnoDB: 5.5.43 started; log sequence number 11731761
150427 23:01:08 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '192.168.1.234'; port: 3306
150427 23:01:08 [Note]   - '192.168.1.234' resolves to '192.168.1.234';
150427 23:01:08 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '192.168.1.234'.
150427 23:01:08 [ERROR] Can't start server: Bind on TCP/IP port: Cannot assign requested address
150427 23:01:08 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on port: 3306 ?
150427 23:01:08 [ERROR] Aborting
```

changing the

```
 bind-address
```

in

```
 /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

to the current ip 
and restarting the server

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible problems with Mysql package:

1. Really a space problem:

   Many distributions have their /var directory in the original root partition which is not made big enough by default to hold real-life data. They usually create separate partition for /usr with tons of space

   Check this and you will get full details and your answer

   https://serverfault.com/questions/256729/error-the-partition-with-var-lib-mysql-is-too-full
2. It is a bug which might not have been fixed and to fix it follow this article:

   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-dfsg-5.0/+bug/118523

Answer (score 1):

I have faced same issue, in my case there is another mysql service was running

```
$ ps -aux | grep mysql
mysql     7241  0.0  5.1 562600 52812 ?        Ssl  13:36   0:02 /usr/sbin/mysql
ubuntu   13580  0.0  0.0  10468   916 pts/0    S+   15:50   0:00 grep --color=au

$ sudo kill  7241
```

Then I started mysql.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
* Starting MySQL database server mysqld                                 [ OK ]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the partition `/var` there are several directories that accumulate many files which can fill up the partition.

In my case logs are saved in `/var/logs` filling up `/var` prevented me from starting mysql.

I deleted some of those old logs and that solved my problem. If you do not have log rotation it is better that you try acerlo since if you do not have this process the logs can add up to many GB in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was that `/var` was full:

```sh
$ df -h  # More info with du -h /var | sort -hr | head -10
...
/dev/sda3       2.7G  2.7G     0 100% /var
```

So I just used [`ncdu`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ncdu) (another nice tool is [`dust`](https://github.com/bootandy/dust)) to check what was taking so much space:

```
sudo ncdu /var
```

Delete some useless stuff with `d`, restarted

```
sudo systemctl restart mysql.service
```

And voilà, everything working now.

What to delete? Each case should be analyzed carefully. Start with `sudo apt autoremove`, [snap stuff](https://askubuntu.com/a/1141683/349837), [rotate your logs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log_rotation) and maybe remove old stuff/backups: `/var/crash`, `/var/cache`, `/var/tmp`…

Comment: Can you provide some example of useless stuff?

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas I added some examples to the post :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was just the date was wrong. Somehow, after a blade failure (it is a VM), the OS started up with a wring date. Once i changed to the corrent date, mysql started correctly

Answer (score -1):

Run the command `sudo apt-get --reinstall install mysql-server` to re-install MySQL. It will re-create the missing directories and allow you to start the server again.

Comment: This is what I got:
`dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.`
How do I use --configure?