# MySQL partition /var/lib/mysql is full BUT it is not full

Tags: partitioning, mysql

i have the same issue as this old thread "[MySQL error: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/482923/mysql-error-the-partition-with-var-lib-mysql-is-too-full)" but the answer offered is not working for me (which is to do a sudo mysql stop & a sudo mysql start)

To resume, when i try to restart mysql, i have the error :

```
Permission Denied  
/var/lib/mysql is too full
```

but when i use the command df, here is what i got

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1,9G  4,0K  1,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           387M  1,5M  385M   1% /run
/dev/sda2       913G   15G  852G   2% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            1,9G   54M  1,9G   3% /run/shm
none            100M   12K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sda1       511M  3,4M  508M   1% /boot/efi
```

and here is the answer i get from df -i when i am in the folder

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             490671    533   490138    1% /dev
tmpfs            494563    604   493959    1% /run
/dev/sda2      60760064 283468 60476596    1% /
none             494563      2   494561    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
none             494563      3   494560    1% /run/lock
none             494563     60   494503    1% /run/shm
none             494563     17   494546    1% /run/user
/dev/sda1             0      0        0     - /boot/efi
```

and when i just do df -i /var/lib/mysql

```
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      60760064 284097 60475967    1% /
```

I don't know if i am missing something but to me this is not full, i tried apt-get clean, it worked and then the issue is back as soon as the system start again. Also, rebooting didn't help.

So if anyone has some idea, i would appreciate it, thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add the output of `df -i /var/lib/mysql`.

Comment: There is [this story](http://serverfault.com/questions/629097/mysql-error-the-partition-with-var-lib-mysql-is-too-full-df-h-shows-otherw) from someone who started `mysql` as non-root user, and got this error. It was really a permissions problem, the space message was a red herring.

Comment: Not really this, i am pretty sure i messed up because i have tried few different things on my own, but here i am with this error when i am starting mysql (with sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart) : [error log](http://pastebin.com/JQQRMuNW)  It might be awkward but i didn't manage to find the file they talke about

Comment: Ah ok. Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576745/innodb-error-space-header-page-consists-of-zero-bytes-in-data-file-ibdata1) help? The answer to that question contains a safe basic conf file to start from. The file mentioned in your error log is `/var/lib/mysql/ibdata1` and it is the file that holds your actual data. So it's pretty important.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for your help. I found the solution [here](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/05/09/mysql-failed-registration-of-innodb-as-a-storage-engine/) the flush line was no longer working tho and generate an error. So, i don't know why i had the Partition full in the first place, but then i supress one database, manually and it probably generate all of this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the different link that can help you (thank you to Jos and the people who answer this different topic)

[Using the proper command to restart MysQL](https://serverfault.com/questions/629097/mysql-error-the-partition-with-var-lib-mysql-is-too-full-df-h-shows-otherw)

[Editing your innoDB Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26576745/innodb-error-space-header-page-consists-of-zero-bytes-in-data-file-ibdata1)
Careful to the Flush command, it might generate error (was the case for me, maybe it was because i didn't do the last step properly)

[How to make the change works and not crash MySQL](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/05/09/mysql-failed-registration-of-innodb-as-a-storage-engine/)